# Regex find image with attribute not wrapped in a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am working on a regex that if it's true, does some string manipulations but at the moment my code is getting triggered too often so I need it to be more specific. Regex really isn't my strong suite - my current regex is

```
if(/(?!<a(.*?))<img src="(.*?[^<])" data-special="(t:).*"/.test(str)) {
    // do this code
}
```

My regex **needs to find img elements that have a certain attribute value that are not surrounded by a href/wrapped in a link**. For instance I want it to capture the following:

```
<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" data-special="t:https://www.twitter.com" />
```

and replace it with

```
<a href="http://example.com/"><img src="http://example.com/image.jpg" data-special="t:https://www.twitter.com" /></a>
```

So the `if` statement will only be true if there is an `img` tag in the string where the `data-special` attribute exists and that contains `t:` followed by any link. Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

In your simple case, it would be enough to use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector and [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) function:

```js
$('*:not(a) > img[data-special^="t:"]').wrap('<a href="http://example.com/"></a>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://example.com/image1.jpg" data-special="t:https://www.twitter.com" />
<a href=""><img src="http://example.com/image4.jpg" data-special="t:https://www.twitter.com" /></a>
<img src="http://example.com/image2.jpg" data-special="t:https://www.twitter.com" />
<img src="http://example.com/image3.jpg" data-special="t:https://www.twitter.com" />
```

> Is it possible to convert that jQuery element check into a conditional
>   for my if statement? So only enter that if-block if there is something
>   to wrap?

```
var imgs = $('*:not(a) > img[data-special^="t:"]');
if (imgs.length) {
    imgs.wrap('<a href="http://example.com/"></a>');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Is it possible to convert that jQuery element check into a conditional for my if statement? So only enter that if-block if there is something to wrap?